# Nested Forms: Copy fields_for from another object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

Implemented [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) for a has_may relationship between Person and Post models.

```
class Person
  has_many :posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts
end
```

It works well. Now there is button "Copy Person" that redirects to new person page by per populating all attributes of previous person. All the fields of person is populated except the posts of that person. Here is the view code of rendering posts:

```
<%= f.fields_for :posts do |ff| %>
    <%= render 'post_fields', ff: ff %>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
def copy_person
  @person = Person.new
  @previous_person = Person.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to new_person_url(@person)
end
```

If a person has 3 posts and it should populate all fields of person and should display 3 posts as well while copying it. The previous person object is available on view as `@previous_person`

What change I need in view to render those posts?

Comment: is copied person persisted in the DB? Could you please provide controller code?

Comment: Yes its persisted and available on view as @previous_person

Comment: I assume that you copy just person without theirs posts. So that's why you can see just person itself and no posts at all.

Comment: Actually it redirects to new person url where it populates values from previous person which is persisted. Like `<%= f.text_field :name, value: @previous_person.name %>` something like this. I need something similar for posts as well

Comment: Updated the question and added the controller method to copy person

Comment: Still unclear. Could toy please provide the whole controller action?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115286/discussion-between-arif-and-retgoat).

Answer (score 1):

Please consider to create new person and theirs posts according to previous_person's attributes

```
def copy_person
  previous_person = Person.find(params[:id])
  @person = Person.create!(previous_person.attributes.except("id"))
  previous_person.posts.each do |old_posts|
    @person.posts.create!(old_posts.attributes.except("id"))
  end
end
```

Now you have newly created person copied from the previous one with all posts. Also, you can use `dup` method to create a copy of person

```
def copy_person
  previous_person = Person.find(params[:id])
  @person = previous_person.dup
  @person.save!
  previous_person.posts.each do |old_posts|
    @person.posts.create!(old_posts.attributes.except("id"))
  end
end
```